# Can I safely sell salvage items?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

The resources tab of the inventory has some categories that are obviously crafting materials like minerals, tech materials and bio materials. But there is also a category "salvage", and I accumulated a lot of stuff there already in the short time I played the trial:

[image]

This looks suspiciously like stuff that is only good for selling and has no additional purpose. But before I get rid of all of it, I'd like to make sure that there is no further use for these items in game.

Are salvage items safe to sell, or do they have some use in the game?

Comment: I'm sure that when I hit my first merchant, there was a "Sell all salvage items" button.  This is a very strong hint that these are just "vendor trash" and the game expects you to unconditionally sell them to the next merchant you come across.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same concern at first, but somewhere in the vast array of the UI, I found a tooltip that describes salvage as items which are "useless to the Pathfinder", and can be safely sold. I can't provide a screenshot of it, as my trial has expired, and I can't even remember where I saw it.
So, if you trust me, they're only for selling.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://twinfinite.net/2017/03/mass-effect-andromeda-what-to-do-with-salvage-items/):

> While these Salvage items may initially sound important due to their overly complicated scientific names, they’re actually not all that useful to the Pathfinder. This means that you should sell them for extra Credits.
>
> Simply head to any kiosk (there’s one on the Tempest, and you can find stores all around the galaxy too) and choose to sell your items. Head over to the Salvage category, and sell all of the junk you have there. As you accumulate more of these items, you’ll be able to get a nice sum of Credits that can be put into purchasing more useful items like weapon mods and different types of ammo. These Salvage items can’t be used to upgrade your gear in any way either, so don’t be afraid to let them go for extra money.

To paraphrase, the items are "not much use" to the Pathfinder and can safely be sold.